# ¿Cómo calcular la moda de un valor en DataFrame en función de dos columnas y solo a unas variables específicas?

Tags: python, pandas

Agradecería su ayuda, tengo un inconveniente con una consulta en python, tengo un arreglo de las variables categóricas y necesito aplicar la moda solo a estas variables, encontré un ejemplo pero me genera error al modificarlo en la parte `df[col].groupby(['Marca_y_Modelo']...`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Combustible': ['Diesel', 'Gasolina', np.nan, 'Diesel', 'Gasolina', 'Diesel', 'Gasolina', np.nan, np.nan, 'Diesel'],
                   'Marca_y_Modelo': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Motor': ['UNO', 'UNO', np.nan, np.nan, 'UNO', 'UNO', 'TRES', 'DOS', 'DOS', 'UNO'],
                   'Tipo': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', np.nan, 'GGG', 'DDD', np.nan, 'PPP', 'YYY', 'NNN']})

variablesCateg= ['Combustible', 'Motor']
for col in variablesCateg:
  df[col] = df[col].groupby(['Marca_y_Modelo'], group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
print(df)
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas aplicando *groupby* a cada columna categórica (serie) e intentando agrupar por *Marca_y_Modelo*, clave que no existe lógicamente en la serie. Debes aplicar *groupby* al dataframe no a la columna:

```
variables_categ= ['Combustible', 'Motor']
group = df.groupby(['Marca_y_Modelo'], group_keys=False)
for col in variables_categ:
    df[col] = group[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente era eso.